# IDEA import of Maven GitHub projects not working/running -> "Cannot resolve symbol"

Tags: maven, spring-boot, github, intellij-idea, import

**#### UPDATE v2 ####**

Ok I found out the issue, it was in fact an IDEA bug. More precisely, it's the git extension, gitflowincrementalbuilder, which from 3.8+ breaks Idea. Changing version to 3.7 solves it, for now.

https://github.com/vackosar/gitflow-incremental-builder/issues/91

Intellij/git, please fix it

---

------ Old Update v1 -----

I just tried running the project with Eclipse... works perfectly without any issues whatsoever, at first try... So it's kind of a Intellij-IDEA bug/problem (...)

---

I am trying to run some examples from Github, the spring spring-boot ones from baeldung.com; more specifically this one (no one works in idea): https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-mvc-simple-2

While it works using Maven commands, "mvn clean install"
and then "mvn spring-boot:run", wont work in Idea (it does clean and install ok, but no run). Project is imported using "New"->"Project from Existing Sources" (check images below for settings).

I think there is some problem with the pom imported configuration, especially since there is a multi module structure (parent tag); cannot even resolve @SpringBootApplication.

```
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>spring-mvc-simple-2</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>spring-mvc-simple-2</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.baeldung</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-boot-2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../parent-boot-2</relativePath>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>spring-mvc-simple2</finalName>
</build>
```

I have been trying to add a SpringBoot configuration manually using IDEA gui but it doesnt recognize the application class (?). What partially works though is replacing the parent pom with:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Tests still wont work, but I dont think u're supposed to change/edit the pom file manually to make things works...

I have been trying alot already: invalidate cache, maven reimport & Generate sources and update folders, using mvn first, checking all jdk configuration... nothing works.

[image: Idea_Import_Step1]
[image: Idea_Import_Step2]
[image: Idea_Import_Step3]
[image: Idea_Error_After_Import]

Comment: If you import only one subproject than it's better to change it to independent project. Remove <parent> section, add groupId and version (e.g.  <groupId>com.baeldung</groupId><version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>) and set version for spring dependency

Comment: You need to import the project as a maven project not as a regular java project. If you do the latter nothing will be imported. Next to that you need to import the `tutorial` project not one of the sub projects.

Comment: @y.bedrov Yep that works too, but you have to make changes manually which it's not easy nor efficient when the project/example is actually big

Comment: Context is key here and that is lost in Intellij (partially), it can not reference the parent project because it doesn't know it, hence it needs to retrieve it from the m2 repository where it non-existing. When doing it from the command line the context is still there. Also not sure why it would take that long (especially if you first build it on the commandline all the libraries should already be downloaded).

Comment: @M.Deinum hmmm but the parent project is actually well referenced in the pom, and that's why u can build&run perfectly using the mvn commands in the subfolder/submodule only (so building only the submodule + parent pom  dependencies needed). Also Idea can find the parent pom (relativePath tag), but somehow the whole thing doesnt work properly ##### I think it took long because i had "search for projects recursively" selected, without I can import the whole project but I still have the same issues

Comment: Because Intelllij cannot replace the parent with a project reference, it needs it to be available in the M2 repository. Intellij cannot analuze what isn't part of the project. It might be able to see the pom, it cannot see the actual project.

Comment: @M.Deinum Why cant Intelli-j, though? I mean Mvn can, Eclipse can (look update above), only IDEA cant... which btw is supposed to be the best. Also no way to fix it either (so far)

Comment: You are comparing apples and oranges (the process of supporting maven in both IDEs is different). What Intellij tries to do is replace a dependency with a project reference, however as the project isn't part of your imported project that won't work.  Hence the actual created jar for the parent has to be published somewhere (local or remote repository). As it isn't, parent cannot be resolved and thus your project won't work. Import the whole project (select the tutorial project. don't scan recursivly, import it, then individually add the sub project you want as maven project).

Comment: Another thing, which version of the IDE are you actually using Community or Ultimate? And which maven version are you using? Intellij itself ships with an old maven version (3.3.6) which you might want to reconfigure to a newer version (which might help).

Comment: @M.Deinum It's ultimate, maven3 version 3.3.9. I tried importing the whole project, and then adding the sub project/module as maven, but it's still not working/running (same issue). Idk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't build the parent module so IntelliJ does not find this in your local Maven repository.

You should run `mvn install` in the project: 
https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/parent-boot-2/pom.xml

But also exchanging the parent helps like you described yourself.

To make the tests run you have to add the test dependency from the parent:

```
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: <parent-boot-2> also calls <parent-modules> as parent; now I did try to import the whole project in Idea from the main directory, but after 1hour it was still importing&resolving... so I closed it (it's huge). Anyway with the mvn commands u can build the single sub-modules, then why cant you with Idea? Doesnt seem right. ##### About the test, yes adding from the parent pom fixed it (also worked adding <org.junit.jupiter> dependecy using Idea Alt+Enter)

Comment: I would suggest that you build everthing outside Idea then you have all the dependencies in your local maven repo. After that you can import any sub module in Idea without any issue.

Comment: Btw. If my answer was helpful I would appreciate if you could accept it. Thank you

Comment: I upvoted your answer, but still cant manage to make Idea import works :| what should i do exactly? I tried to "mvn clean install" in the main project path, and then in every used sub-module; then one time I imported the submodule another the whole main project, still the same issue cannot resolve @SpringBootApplication... Also tried mvn idea:idea, nothing. Idk anymore